# How can I store the length of a line into a var withing awk script?

Tags: awk, ksh

I have this simple awk script with which I attempt to check the amount of characters in the first line.
if the first line has more of less than 10 characters I want to store the amount 
of caracters into a var. 
Somehow the first print statement works but storing that result into a var doesn't.
Please help. 
I tried removing dollar sign " **thelength=(length($0))**"
and removing the parenthesis "**thelength=length($0)**" but it doen't print anything...

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/ksh
awk ' BEGIN {FS=";"}
{
 if (NR==1)
        if(length($0)!=10) 
    {
    print(length($0))
    thelength=$(length($0))
    print "The length of the first line is: ",$thelength;
    exit 1;
    }
    }
    END { print "STOP"  }' $1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues dealing with mixing `ksh` and `awk` scripting ...

- no need to make a sub-shell call within `awk` to obtain the length; use `thelength=length($0)`
- `awk` variables do not require a leading `$` when being referenced; use `print ... ,thelength`

So your code becomes:

```
#!/bin/ksh
awk ' BEGIN {FS=";"}
{
 if (NR==1)
        if(length($0)!=10) 
    {
    print(length($0))
    thelength=length($0)
    print "The length of the first line is: ",thelength;
    exit 1;
    }
    }
    END { print "STOP"  }' $1
```